# Open high resolution image without affecting quality

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

How to open high resolution image in HTML 5 canvas

Unable to open images of resolution more than 20000*20000

I want to open without affecting quality

Comment: What do you mean by open?

Comment: I want to display high resolution image